# Is RTX 2060 (12 GB) or RTX 3060 (12 GB) suitable for complex deep learning tasks?

Tags: deep-learning, gpu

After many months of saving, I can now afford to buy RTX 3060 (12GB). However, I am afraid to waste my money after saving them for months. I am preparing myself for starting my Ph.D. degree. It will be related to applying deep learning in the medical domain, so I am expecting to run complex models, such as Xception, on large datasets ( and maybe I will use GANs). Moreover, I read that RTX 2060 (12GB ) is a good GPU for deep learning. So please guide me in putting my money in the right place. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I suggest not buying a GPU for your PhD work with your personal money. Many PhDs are supported by grants and grants generally pay for equipment. Are PhDs in Astronomy at the same institution buying telescopes with their personal money?

Comment: I strongly agree with Brian, buy a computer if you want but not for work. Among other options, inquire with your IT department whether your university provides (or has access to) a high performance cluster. This has become common and it often provides much more computing power than any individual computer (to give you an idea, the one I have access to has machines with 512GB memory and multiple GPUs).

Comment: Thanks a lot for all of you guys.

Comment: Might be interesting to check the free tiers of GPU providers first.